# How to remove elements with missing field in a MongoDB array?

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, pymongo

Recently I'm learning MongoDB and Python by myself and I encounter this problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/acQxl.png

[image]

For `object 1-3` there is `date` information in it but some object does not contain date on it. How can I remove the `object that doesn't contain date` in it by using MongoDB and Python script?Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Remove missing data" is contradictory. Either you have data which you like to remove or the data is missing. Please don't paste images, provide documents as formatted text, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try

```
update(
{} ,
{ "$pull": { data :{ date: { "$exists":  false } }} },
false,true)
```

Comment: This command is not working in my MongoDB..it popout unknown expression $exists

Comment: If you use with double cotatiob or without $ whats happend?

Comment: I manage to get it run on my MongoDB.thanks.Is this the same way to do in Python 3?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$pull` to remove items from the array.

[$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

Find part of `update`:  Use `$exists` on `date` field to check the existence.

```
db.coll.update({},
{
  "$pull": {
    "arr": {
      "a": {
        exists: false
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I thought of using $pull but I thought pull is for existing data.Can you show me the command for my question above?Thanks

Comment: ```db.coll.update({},
{
  "$pull": {
    "arr": {
      "a": {
        exists: false
      }
    }
  }
})``` Please try this